# Why do `max` and `min` have such strange behavior with numpy.nan?

Tags: python, python-3.x, max, nan, min

I accidentally stumbled upon some strange behavior with `max`, `min` and `numpy.nan` and I'm curious about what's going on under the hood.

Consider the following code run in python3:

```
import numpy as np

max(np.nan, 0)     # outputs nan 
max(np.nan, 10000) # outputs nan
max(0, np.nan)     # outputs 0
max(10000, np.nan) # outputs 10000
```

I've played around with a number of values, and it seems that the first value given is always what's returned. The same behavior can be observed with `min`. I would have expected the output to consistently be `nan`, or even to throw an error, but this is quite unexpected. `Math.nan` does the same thing.

I'm very curious about this behavior -- does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @sascha He's calling the standard Python `min` and `max`, and his arguments make sense for that.

Comment: There's nothing numpy-specific here. You'll get the same behavior with `math.nan`, or `decimal.Decimal('nan')`, or anything that follows the defined semantics for NaN. (Well, `Decimal` and `numpy` lets you configure IEEE-style flags for NaN behavior, and you're using signaling NaNs by default, so you could make it raise, e.g., `InvalidOperation` from `decimal`.) You could even make a completely different type with semantics that aren't the same as NaN except as far as they define a "quiet" partial ordering and come up with similar weirdness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write your own version of `max`.  Remember that `NaN` will cause any greater, equal, or less comparison to return `False`.  For instance,

```
def my_max(iter):
    result = iter[0]
    for val in iter[1:]:
        if result < val:
            result = val
    return result
```

When you begin with a number, the comparison fails, and that number becomes the result.  When you start with `nan`, *any* comparison fails, and the result is stuck at that initial `nan` value.

It's not always the first value, just what you get with the above mechanics.  For instance:

```
>>> nan = numpy.nan
>>> max([7, nan, 15, nan, 5])
15
>>> max([nan, 7, nan, 15, nan, 5])
nan
```

Answer (score 2):

`max` doesn't know anything about floats or NaN. It assumes that there actually is an ordering relationship between the arguments, and it may produce nonsensical results when there is no such relationship, as is the case with NaN.

`numpy.maximum` behaves more reasonably:

```
>>> numpy.maximum(numpy.nan, 1)
nan
>>> numpy.maximum(1, numpy.nan)
nan
```